# CloudFront - push group of files, when one file is accessed?

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I have groupings of files that I would like to be distributed to the edge server, when one of them is accessed.  I.e. if we have the below 5 files in a bucket, and a user accesses "username/uniqueid.3.jpg" I would like to have all 5 "username/uniqueid*.jpg" distributed to the same edge server that "username/uniqueid.3.jpg" is going to be distributed to.  Can this be done in the distribution setup with wildcards, in code with wildcards, by zipping the files (I'm more than ok with this), or another way?

username/uniqueid.1.jpg
username/uniqueid.2.jpg
username/uniqueid.3.jpg
username/uniqueid.4.jpg
username/uniqueid.5.jpg

Thank you,
Tim

Comment: This is not something CloudFront does.  It is strictly pull-through.  What are you trying to accomplish -- pre-warming one edge location's cache for a specific user?

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon CloudFront uses a pull-model** at its edge locations. This means that content is only loaded into an edge location when a request is received. There is no capability to "push" content into edge locations. (This differs from Akamai, which does use a "push" model.)

In theory, you could do it by request the URL at every edge location, but requests are **automatically directed to the closest edge location** (based on latency). So, you'd either need to generate requests in 50+ locations, or you'd have to figure out how to "appear" to be in those locations.

The only benefit would be a faster initial serve of a file, and then it would probably expire after 24 hours anyway.